# Problem with placement of subfigure captions

Tags: subcaption

I am using the `subcaption` package and I want to know how to place the captions of the subfigures in the bottom center of each subfigure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%
%
\usepackage{utopia} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[superscript,ref,nomove]{cite}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{verbatim, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm} 
\usepackage[british]{babel} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,rotating} 
\usepackage{array,warpcol} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{fixme} 
\usepackage[section,verbose]{placeins}
\usepackage{gensymb,units}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{stfloats}
%
\usepackage[width=11cm,font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf%
,format=hang,labelformat=parens,labelsep=endash,%
justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=on]{caption} % Captions.
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{width=6cm,font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf%
,format=hang,labelformat=parens,labelsep=endash,%
justification=centering,singlelinecheck=on}
%
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[pageanchor=true,plainpages=false,pagebackref=false%
,hyperindex=true,hyperfootnotes=true,linktocpage=false%
,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,menucolor=red,bookmarks=true%
,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdftitle={Latitude and Month Correction},pdfauthor={Muhammad Hamdy Al-bassoussi},pdfkeywords={Cooling Load},pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,pdffitwindow=true,pdfmenubar=true%
,pdftoolbar=true,pdfwindowui=true,pdfpagelayout=OneColumn]{hyperref}
%
\graphicspath{{./Figures/}} %To set the first directory to search for images in.
%
%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
%\parindent0em
%\parskip\medskipamount
%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\bfseries{\thepage}}
\rfoot{\scriptsize\bf{Latitude \& Month Correction}}
\lfoot{\scriptsize\bf{M. Hamdy}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
%\addtolength{\headheight}{0pt} % make space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
%\fancyfoot{}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
%
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5} % To edit the height of the rows of a table.
%


\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height= 6cm, width=12cm]{W80_32N_Sep_S}
\caption{Wall no.(80): 32$^\circ$N - September - South orientaion}
\label{fig:w80}
\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[height= 6cm, width=12cm]{W17_56N_Apr_NE}
\caption{Wall no.(17): 56$^\circ$N - April - NourthEast orientaion}
\label{fig:w17}
\end{subfigure}%
\qquad
\caption{Comparing Corrected CLTDs Resulting from Equations~(\ref{eq:corr}) and~(\ref{eq:corr_ash}) with the Calculated CLTDs for Two Different Wall Constructions, Locations, Months, and Orientations.}\label{fig:corr}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image: The image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your posting to include the code that you use to generate the figure (and subfigures). It would appear that the subfigure widths have been set in a certain way; unfortunately, without seeing the code, it's going to be difficult to diagnose and fix the problem.

Comment: I have already edited my post and I am waiting for your answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a `subfigure` with width of `0.3\textwidth` and a width of `6cm` in `\captionsetup[sub]`. The caption is centered within that width. But the figure width (as in `\includegraphics[height= 6cm, width=12cm]`) is more than that. Hence all this trouble.

Remedies:

1. Don't use more width in `\includegraphics[width=..]` than given in `\begin{subfigure}{....}` and use same width in both `\captionsetup[sub]` as well.
2. It is better to give only width in `\includegraphics[width=..]`. If you include `height`, you should use `keepaspectratio` to prevent the figure from getting distorted.

Use something like

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Wall no.(80): 32$^\circ$N - September - South orientaion}
\label{fig:w80}
\end{subfigure}%
\hfill                              %% note this addition
\begin{subfigure}{6cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{Wall no.(17): 56$^\circ$N - April - NourthEast orientaion}
\label{fig:w17}
\end{subfigure}%
\qquad
\caption{Comparing Corrected CLTDs Resulting from Equations~(\ref{eq:corr}) and~(\ref{eq:corr_ash}) with the Calculated CLTDs for Two Different Wall Constructions, Locations, Months, and Orientations.}\label{fig:corr}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: It works :) ... Really thank you very very much :)

Comment: @Muhammad Glad it worked. `:-)`

Comment: Two quick notes: (i) Because the graphs in the subfigures are set up to take up all of the available width, there's no need to provide `\centering` instructions inside the `subfigure` environments. Second, because the graphs are designed to use the entire available width of the subfigure environments, I'd use `width=\linewidth` instead of a hard-coded value (here: `width=6cm`) in the optional arguments of the `\includegraphics` directives. That way, if the widths ever have to be changed later on, one only has to adjust one parameter rather than two.

Comment: @Mico Good points. I agree. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell for sure from your setup if you want the graphs in the subfigures to be 6 centimeters wide -- as would seem to be indicated by the arguments of the `\subcaption` statements -- or 12 centimeters wide -- as would seem to be indicated by the optional arguments of the `\includegraphics` statements).

If it's the former, and if you want the two graphs to be placed next to each other, you should follow the code that Harish has provided in his separate answer.

If it's the latter, i.e., if the two graphs should each be 12 centimeters wide, they can't fit side by side on an A4-sized page. In this case, you may want to adopt something along the following lines. Note that the codes sets up a `minipage` of width `12cm`; within this environment, all width references are to `\linewidth` (which will be `12cm`) rather than to a hard-coded length value.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{utopia}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" for real doc
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf,
            format=hang, labelformat=parens,
            labelsep=endash, justification=raggedright,
            singlelinecheck=on]{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\captionsetup[sub]{font=footnotesize,
            labelsep=endash, justification=centering}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
% Create a `minipage` that's 12cm wide
% Then, use `\linewidth` parameter inside the `minipage` environment
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{W80_32N_Sep_S}
   \caption{Wall no.(80): 32$^\circ$N -- September -- South orientation}
   \label{fig:w80}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip % insert a bit more vertical space between subfigures
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{W17_56N_Apr_NE}
   \caption{Wall no.(17): 56$^\circ$N -- April -- NorthEast orientation}
   \label{fig:w17}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Comparing Corrected CLTDs Resulting from Equations~(\ref{eq:corr}) 
   and~(\ref{eq:corr_ash}) with the Calculated CLTDs for Two Different Wall 
   Constructions, Locations, Months, and Orientations.}
\label{fig:corr}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico : Thanks a lot for your great notes, and I am sorry since I have noticed your answer just now :)